# how to get header from SSL response and parse it in Proxy Server in c#?

Tags: c#

i created a proxy server in c# to replace my file on local
for example :

i get http header with HttpListener and parse it to take file url and then i build a fake Response to download the file from my local , but is it possible to do that with HTTPS too ?
i tried to do it but i get only CONNECT request type.
if is it possible , how can i do this ?

url is like this : https://sgst.prod.dl.playstation.net/sgst/prod/00/PPSA01876_00/app/info/62/f_c2855f23a9de280972d5dc1c1fae07240bb76193a65393a6e304588ffb111b8a/UP0001-PPSA01876_00-FARCRY6GAME00000.crc

and in fiddler :
[This is Tunnel with CONNECT request type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEmYn.jpg)
and what i want to get is :
[This is HTTPS GET request type with URL that i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re74N.jpg)

so this is my code but i get host only (Host: sgst.prod.dl.playstation.net)

```
    private void QueryHandle(string query)
    {
        HeaderFields = ParseQuery(query);
        if ((HeaderFields == null) || !HeaderFields.ContainsKey("Host"))
            SendBadRequest();
        else
        {
            int num;
            string requestedPath;
            int index;
            if (HttpRequestType.ToUpper().Equals("CONNECT"))
            {
                index = RequestedPath.IndexOf(":");
                if (index >= 0)
                {
                    requestedPath = RequestedPath.Substring(0, index);
                    num = RequestedPath.Length > (index + 1) ? int.Parse(RequestedPath.Substring(index + 1)) : 443;
                }
                else
                {
                    requestedPath = RequestedPath;
                    num = 80;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                index = HeaderFields["Host"].IndexOf(":");
                if (index > 0)
                {
                    requestedPath = HeaderFields["Host"].Substring(0, index);
                    num = int.Parse(HeaderFields["Host"].Substring(index + 1));
                }
                else
                {
                    requestedPath = HeaderFields["Host"];
                    num = 80;
                }
                if (HttpRequestType.ToUpper().Equals("POST"))
                {
                    int tempnum = query.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n");
                    _mHttpPost = query.Substring(tempnum + 4);
                }
            }

            var localFile = String.Empty;
            if (MonitorLog.RegexUrl(RequestedUrl))
                localFile = UrlOperate.MatchFile(RequestedUrl);

            _uinfo.PsnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_uinfo.PsnUrl) ? RequestedUrl : _uinfo.PsnUrl;

            if (!HttpRequestType.ToUpper().Equals("CONNECT") && localFile != string.Empty && File.Exists(localFile))
            {
                _uinfo.ReplacePath = localFile;
                _updataUrlLog(_uinfo);
                SendLocalFile(localFile, HeaderFields.ContainsKey("Range") ? HeaderFields["Range"] : null, HeaderFields.ContainsKey("Proxy-Connection") ? HeaderFields["Proxy-Connection"] : null);
            }

            if (HttpRequestType.ToUpper().Equals("CONNECT"))
            {
                IPHostEntry hostEntry;
                hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(requestedPath);
                string server = hostEntry.AddressList[0].ToString();

                IPAddress hostIp = IPAddress.Parse(server);
                var remoteEp = new IPEndPoint(hostIp, num);

                DestinationSocket = new Socket(remoteEp.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                DestinationSocket.BeginConnect(remoteEp, OnConnected, DestinationSocket);



                _uinfo.Host = hostEntry.AddressList[0].ToString();
                _uinfo.ReplacePath = string.Empty;
                _updataUrlLog(_uinfo);

            }

    private void OnConnected(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            if (DestinationSocket == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            string str;
            DestinationSocket.EndConnect(ar);

            if (HttpRequestType.ToUpper().Equals("CONNECT"))
            {
                if (ClientSocket != null)
                {
                    str = HttpVersion + " 200 Connection Established\r\n\r\n";
                    ClientSocket.BeginSend(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str), 0, str.Length, SocketFlags.Partial,
                        OnOkSent, ClientSocket);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                str = RebuildQuery();
                DestinationSocket.BeginSend(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str), 0, str.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                                            OnQuerySent, DestinationSocket);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void OnOkSent(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ClientSocket != null && ClientSocket.EndSend(ar) == -1)
            {
                Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                StartRelay();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }
```

so i am not familiar with socket , ssl , protocols ...
i will thank you for your help and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: my problem is i cannot get GET request type Header value in SSL , i get only CONNECT Header value! look at the pictures : [this is what i only get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEmYn.jpg) and [This is what i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re74N.jpg) . so i do not know is it possible to get it or not , if is it possible , how can i ?